# rails 3 link_to with ONLY_path = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This doesn't give the full URL, which breaks as it's in a mailer

```
<%= link_to @conversation.title, conversations_path %>
```

This gives me the full URL, which is good:

```
<%= conversations_url(:only_path => false) %>
```

How do I get the best of both worlds? I want to link_to but have the full path?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without testing this.. Have you tried this?

```
<% conversations_url(:only_path => false) do %>   
  @conversation.title 
<% end &>
```

Comment: I don't understand this, does this actually create a link?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Oluf, ran into your answer when I was trying to fix a similiar problem.

The link may be rewritten into:

```
<%= link_to( @conversation.title, conversations_url( :only_path => false)) %>
```