# How do i convert a link_to from being relative to absolute in rails, when I have parameters, url_for, but how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the current link, but recently realized that my output needs to be absolute_url with the port.

```
link_to key_status, "/attendants/update_player_status/game/#{game.id}/#{key_status}/user_hash/#{user_hash}"
```

which after processing returns:

```
<a href="/attendants/update_player_status/game/4/no/user_hash/a_hash_here" class="ui-link">no</a>
```

I would like this link to be absolute and am looking at url_for, except im not sure how to pass in the dynamic parameters, and created an absolute link, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the :only_path parameter like so:

```
:only_path => false
```

Comment: That does not work:

<%= link_to "kamil", new_team_path, :only_path=>false%>

produces:

<a href="/teams/new" only_path="false" class="ui-link">kamil</a>

Comment: Try passing it in with your url, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181646/rails-3-link-to-with-only-path-false